# How to return request payload in response

Tags: kong

I was easily able to set up a service with routes and they are basically functioning. However, one of my needs is to return the request payload in the response.

I have tried using the response transformer, plugin doesn't appear to give me any access to the request. (Also, the feature to replace the response body entirely appears to be a feature available only using the advanced response transformer, which is only on the enterprise tier.)

Is there a simple way to do this? Or would I be relegated to creating my own plugin?